# Is sitting cross legged good for anterior pelvic tilt?

Tags: glutes

i have some APT and associated knee clicking (the latter being the main issue). I believe i got this from cycling/muscle imbalances and lack of stretching. To try and cure this i've been doing strengthening exercises for the glutes and abs,and stretching the hip flexors,groin, calves and piriformis. My goal has been to try and rotate my femurs externally to stop my knee caps clicking on the outer leg.
I've read that sitting cross legged stretches the piriformis (good), but would it also stretch the glutes etc and make APT worse ? So basically is sitting cross legged good for helping cure APT and achieving some external femur rotation?

Comment: How do you know that you have an anterior pelvic tilt? It sounds like a self-diagnose. You really should check with a medical professional and ask him for exercises that help your specific condition.

Comment: Lordosis.rounded shoulders, waist band higher at the back than front. Plus my knees click laterally, suggesting i need some femur external rotation. Too much cycling hills.